# FetchList() in zend Framework not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to run a query in zend frawork. The query is as given below.

```
select * from users where role_id in (3,5) and emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com');
```

I am passing the string

```
$whereString = role_id in (3,5) and emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com');
```

to

```
$this->fetchList($whereString) // where $this is object of users
```

But fetchList() function executes only the first part i.e `role_id in (3,5)`

but not the second part i.e `emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com');`

The result from fetchList() contains 'abc@abc.com' and 'cba@cba.com'

fetchList() is:

```
    public function fetchList($where=null, $order=null, $count=null, $offset=null)
        {
                $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($where, $order, $count, $offset);
                $entries   = array();
                foreach ($resultSet as $row)
                {
                        $entry = new Application_Model_Users();
                        $entry->setId($row->id)
                              ->setName($row->name)
                              ->setEmail($row->email)
                        $entries[] = $entry;
                }
                return $entries;
        }
```

fetchAll():

```
   /**
     * Fetches all rows.
     *
     * Honors the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
     *
     * @param string|array|Zend_Db_Table_Select $where  OPTIONAL An SQL WHERE clause or Zend_Db_Table_Select object.
     * @param string|array                      $order  OPTIONAL An SQL ORDER clause.
     * @param int                               $count  OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT count.
     * @param int                               $offset OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT offset.
     * @return Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract The row results per the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
     */
    public function fetchAll($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
    {
        if (!($where instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Select)) {
            $select = $this->select();

            if ($where !== null) {
                $this->_where($select, $where);
            }

            if ($order !== null) {
                $this->_order($select, $order);
            }

            if ($count !== null || $offset !== null) {
                $select->limit($count, $offset);
            }

        } else {
            $select = $where;
        }
        print_r($select);
        $rows = $this->_fetch($select);

        $data  = array(
            'table'    => $this,
            'data'     => $rows,
            'readOnly' => $select->isReadOnly(),
            'rowClass' => $this->getRowClass(),
            'stored'   => true
        );

        $rowsetClass = $this->getRowsetClass();
        if (!class_exists($rowsetClass)) {
            require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
            Zend_Loader::loadClass($rowsetClass);
        }
        return new $rowsetClass($data);
    }
```

Any body knows what wrong did I do.

Comment: @drew010 updated the question. Please check

Comment: The only thing that looks out of place is that $whereString isn't a properly quoted php string, but that may be just because of the presentation for the question. Have you tried passing an instance of Zend_Db_Select?

Comment: @Liyali I think emailID and role_id are table columns.

Comment: @RockyFord my bad... my mind was miles away when I wrote that.. :/

Comment: @Liyali, no worries I do the same thing all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out on a bit of limb, because I'm not sure. This feels like it might be a quote issue. Maybe try passing your query string like:

```
//use Zend_Db_Statement to process raw SQL.

//get default adapter
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
//write SQL statement
$sql = "select * from users where role_id in (3,5) and emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com')";
//assuming MySql as DB instantiate object
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($db, $sql);
//Execute SQL Statement accepts optional parameter for array() of values to be bound
$stmt->execute();
```

or you might like to build the query using the select() object:

```
//get default adapter
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
//instantiate the select() object
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select->from('users');
//two where will build an AND query use $select->orWhere() to build an OR query 
$select->where('role_id in (3,5)');
$select->where("emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com')");
$result = $model->fetchList($select);
```

and it might work if `$whereString` were a valid PHP string, beacuse `fetchAll()` accepts a string or an instance of `Zend_Db_Select`:

$whereString = "role_id in (3,5) and emailID not in ('abc@abc.com', 'cba@cba.com')";

Hope this helps some... I took a shot.